# Transactions around finder methods

Tags: java, transactions

Is it wise to start transactions around finder methods:

```
@Transactional
public E getParticularEvent(final String id) {
    return (E)em.find(carClass, id);
}
```

Should this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do nothing else then retrieve a single entity from database there is no reason for using a transaction.